# Google.Gdata and the Google Server API Key

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

18 months ago I developed a Windows Service application using the Google.GData API for use by our Google Apps for Business (now Work) customers.
When I returned to the program I found that my requests return error message
"Execution of authentication request returned unexpected result: 404}"

My program is written in VB.NET and uses Google.GData.Calendar.dll version2.2.0.0 (which seems to still be the latest).

I have looked at OAuth2 authentication but this requires a user interface and I wish to start the service automatically.

I think I need to use a Google Server API Key but I cannot see where I would set it for the GoogleMailSettingsService and CalendarService Google.GData objects that I use. I have not been able to find any examples of how I can use the Google Server API Key.

How do I use the Google Server API Key with the Google.GData API?

Comment: The latest version of the Google calendar api is V3 https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/ the nugget package can be found here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/   I suggest you update to the newest version rather then trying to get Gdata to work.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo I have converted to Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 and can run my program in Visual studio design mode. The authorisation process presents a Web page (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) so that I can Allow the use of the API. However in production I run my program as a Windows Service. When I run the Service it hangs when trying to authorise as I think it cannot interact with the desktop. Do you know if there is a recommended way for Windows Service applications to authorise with the google APIs?

Comment: Is it a calendar that you own personally?  if so you should look into a service account.   If it must be authenticated by the user then I would create a separate application that will allow them to set up the windows service.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo. I can now run my Windows Service using a service account and retrieve Calendar data. My program also retrieved Out Of Office (OOO) data using Google.GData.Apps.GoogleMailSettings.RetrieveVacation. I cannot find a RetrieveVacation function in the new  Google.Apis API. Do you know how I can retrieve OOO data using Google.Apis?